# TypeError: Cannot read property 'babel' of undefined

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, node-modules, babeljs

Following is my package json file. I have installed node_modules successfully. But Getting the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'babel' of undefined"

while running "webpack --watch". 
Please let me know if anyone is aware of this.

```
"axios": "0.16.2",
"babel-plugin-root-import": "^5.1.0",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"chalk": "^2.3.0",
"chart.js": "^2.7.1",
"del": "^3.0.0",
"html-entities": "^1.2.1",
"jquery": "3.1.1",
"karma-es6-shim": "^1.0.0",
"leaflet": "1.0.*",
"less": "2.7.2",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.2.12",
"lodash": "4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.19.1",
"store": "^2.0.12",
"url-loader": "0.5.8",
"vee-validate": "2.0.0-rc.7",
"vue": "2.4.2",
"vue-chartjs": "^2.7.2",
"vue-loader": "12.0.3",
"vue-paginate": "3.4.0",
"vue-resource": "1.2.1",
"vue-router": "2.3.1",
"vue-template-compiler": "2.4.2",
"vuejs-datepicker": "0.6.3",
"vuex": "^2.5.0"


 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.22.0",
```

Answer (score 18):

Your version of babel-loader looks to be out of date. Uninstall it with `npm uninstall babel-loader` and re-install with `npm i -D babel-loader`. You may also need to update to `babel-preset-env` and remove `babel-preset-es2015`

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env/#upgrading-to-babel-preset-env

Answer (score 10):

For me it was a version mismatch between **webpack** and **babel-loader**.

I had `babel-loader@6.2.0` with `webpack@4.12.0`, updating to `babel-loader@7.1.4` fixed the issue for me.